# Home PC power problem caused by fridge

Tags: power, socket

When the fridge stops / starts I can see the Mouse & Keyboard lights spike or dim, sometimes the mouse stops working. These components are connected to a powered usb hub.

I can't use another power line, I have only 1.

**I don't know if the power spike affects my Pc's or Monitor's.**

Electronic devices specs:

- USB Hub - TP-LINK UH700 - Charger IMPUT 100-240V ~50-60Hz 0.8A   OUTPUT 12V 2A
- Mouse Bloody Sniper ZL50 (with lights)
- Keyboard Genesis RX85 (iluminated)
- PSU Corsair SF750
- Display LG 29UM69G 29 inch - Charger IMPUT 100-240V ~50-60Hz 1.4A   OUTPUT 19V 2.53A 48W MAX
- Mini PC Asrrock A300 - Charger IMPUT 100-240V ~50-60Hz 1.8A  OUTPUT 19V 6.32A
- Laptop Lenovo Y720 - Charger IMPUT 100-240V ~50-60Hz 2.5A  OUTPUT 20V 8.5A

★ **Should I get 2 UPS for all devices or just 1 small for Usb Hub?**

.

The fuse box for sockets has this fuse: hager ada332g 32B
https://www.hager.co.uk/product-catalogue/energy-distribution/protection-devices/rcbos/reduced-height-rcbos-type-b-30ma-6ka-1-pole/ada332g/91254.htm
32 AMP   230 V   50 Hz

★ **I don't know if it's safe to plug 2x UPS 2200va in one wall socket, or if the fuse box supports all of this**

I was looking at UPS PowerWalker VI 2200 UPS 1200W https://powerwalker.com/?page=product&item=10120094&lang=en

In final on that line I would have a fridge & 2 UPS

Comment: Once I had this same problem: A small refrigerator which would mess up my usb devices when it cycled on or off. It turned out to be electrical noise _through the air_.  If I plugged the fridge into another outlet, the problem remained. But if I moved the fridge away from the computer, the problem stopped.

Comment: You don't need a second UPS. A single UPS is enough for all your computer and peripherals, since they'll barely use more than 800W. The fridge doesn't need a UPS.

Comment: The distance between Pc & fridge is 5m, can't go any further

Comment: to power all my stuff I need 2 ups of ~ 2000 VA, I have 6 Monitors, 3 PC's, 2 Mini PC Asrock A300, 1 Laptop Lenovo Y720, A few routers, external HDD's . Not all of the pc's will be powered on.

Comment: @Denis Ah, you didn't specify you had a whole internet cafe in your house. haha. But yes, 2 UPS should be fine then.

Comment: One thing to consider is that those are all *maximum* output figures from the power supply for each device you listed. The most extreme example is that the laptop would only possibly draw 8.5A while charging the battery and shouldn't really need UPS backup (just power conditioning) since it has its own battery. The PCs are similar in that their current draw while not being taxed would really look like 1-2A if you measured with something like a Kill-a-watt device

Comment: @Natsu Kage My bad sry. Thx for the update

Comment: @nvuono I wanted to buy a Voltage Regulator for the small chargers, leave the pc's withh a 750W power supply without any protection(hoping that the psu is strong enough to prevent any problems). I was looking at Line-R 600VA Automatic Voltage Regulator https://www.apc.com/shop/uk/en/products/Line-R-600VA-Automatic-Voltage-Regulator/P-LE600I

Comment: @nvuono this avr needs 10% of voltage drop i.e. 23 Volts before it kicks in so it may not be good for me. Acording to a user on amazon "Keephill" 3 stars https://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/B0000C88CR/ref=cm_cr_unknown?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=three_star&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1#reviews-filter-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you live;  the answer to this question will vary.

If you live in a country that actually has 230V 30A plugs (which I'd class as unusual!)  you have a total power budget of 6900W to work with.

Plugging in two 1200W UPS batteries is *well* under this budget;  but keep in mind that you need to avoid going over (typically 70%) of the "peak" load that this breaker will supply;  or around 4900W.

1200W * 2 = 2400W.  (Obviously;  keep in mind that these devices are rated to 1200W Max;  so they will generally only consume anywhere near that when the power has actually gone out and the batteries are discharged.)

TLDR: 
If what you have now works;  adding a UPS or two is unlikely to add significant load to the system;  except immediately after power outages. once your power comes back on;  you *may* trip the breaker if you have a lot of other power-hungry devices also plugged in and left on.

I'd recommend you contact an electrician rather than ask this online;  they will know your local code much better then we will and will be able to answer questions like this.

---

For the record: a 32A breaker is *very* unusual where I live and work; (which is much of North America and significant parts of Europe!)  Given that the breaker you listed is rated at the specific ampacity at such a low operating temperature (30 degrees C) I imagine your local electrical code has derated that value to a more practical temperature rise.  Without knowing the local code;  I cannot confidently say what power that breaker is rated for.

You mentioned "fuse" which is the wrong term for the circuit breaker you linked to;  a "fuse" is permanently destroyed when an over current condition occurs;  where as a breaker mechanically (typically) disconnects the circuit in response to an overcurrent situation.     A breaker can generally be "reset"  while a fuse must be "replaced".

Comment: Thank you for your response! I live in the Isle of Man, city Douglas, is part of the UK. My bad about the "fuse" breaker  is correct. I switched off all the breaker's to test what power lines I have, hoping that an outlet in the kitchen was on a line with the electric cooker, sadly no luck. Power outages are very rare, & I can shut down all this pc's fast. I want to add 2 ups to protect all the equipment, & to run ok when the Fridge starts / stops.

Comment: I've never been to the Isle of Man,  but it appears that you folks use Type C and Type G plugs,  rated to 2.5A (575W) and 13A (3kW) respectively.   The "Type G" are SUPPOSED to be self-fused;  with multiple plugs around the unit connected to a single breaker.  I personally doubt that plugging a power-bar into such an outlet would allow you to dramatically exceed 3kW (but 3kw is more then enough for a pair of 1200W UPS units)

Comment: Cool Thx for the info :)